# Google Drive API - upload file failed c#

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload file to google drive with the api, but it throws me the following error and the upload fails.
request.ResponseBody returns null.
The code has worked for me before and I was able to upload files but it stopped working.

the Code-

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
namespace GoogleDriveApi
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveFile,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveMetadataReadonly,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveReadonly,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveScripts};

        private static string ApplicationName = "GoogleDriveApi";

        static string credentialsPath = ***credentials json file***;
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Authentication for google Drive
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream =
                new FileStream(credentialsPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/drive.googleapis.com1.json");

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }


            // Create Google Drive API service.
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            string filepath = ***TEXT FILE***;
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filepath.ToString()))
            {
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
                body.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filepath.ToString());
                body.Description = "Test Description";
                body.MimeType = "text/plain";
                byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(body, stream, "text/plain");
                request.Fields = "Id";
                request.Upload();
                
                Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody; //returns null value
                Console.WriteLine(file.Id);

            }
       }
}
```

If it matters I saw that the MemoryStream threw the following exceptions-
'stream.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
'stream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

thanks!

Comment: Hi ! Are you getting any error on the console or does it just not return any response? Or is the error the one you mentioned in the last part of your question ```stream.WriteTimeout : System.InvalidOperationException``` and ```stream.ReadTimeout : System.InvalidOperationException```?

Comment: i didnt get any error on the console..

Answer (score 0):

i tried to download the credentials file again and it suddenly worked!
Thanks for trying to help